# How to customize make:auth in laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

make:auth generated register page accepts name,email,password .

i would like to add additional fields dateofbirth,address.

How can i add more fields?

Answer (score 1):

Override the default `register()` method in `RegisterController`. If you don't see any `register()` method, create a new one and write your code to register a new user.

Answer (score 0):

You should

- add the fields you need in the database migration file,
- edit the blade view files (directory resources/views/auth)
- edit the RegisterController create() function and maybe the validator() too. (directory app/Http/Controllers/Auth)